# (Static) Portlet of group: error while rendering

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I've created a static portlet to AuthenticatedUsers group and get this error on page load: **There was an error while rendering the portlet**. Others types portlets generates no error

[image: Page Screenshoot:]

client1/Event.log:

```
2016-06-02T16:43:35 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1464896615.090.768319144619 <site>/front-page/document_view
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module Products.PloneFormGen.patches, line 21, in safe_render
  Module Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile, line 125, in __call__
  Module Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile, line 59, in __call__
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 132, in pt_render
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 240, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 852, in do_condition
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 742, in do_insertStructure_tal
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 218, in evaluateStructure
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
   - URL: /usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.portlet.static-2.0.3-py2.7.egg/plone/portlet/static/static.pt
   - Line 1, Column 0
   - Expression: <PathExpr standard:u'view/transformed'>
   - Names:
      {'args': (),
       'container': <ATDocument at /eleitoral/front-page>,
       'context': <ATDocument at /eleitoral/front-page>,
       'default': <object object at 0x7fc7329c4500>,
       'here': <ATDocument at /eleitoral/front-page>,
       'loop': {},
       'nothing': None,
       'options': {},
       'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x7fc71a6777e0>,
       'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=<site>/front-page/document_view>,
       'root': <Application at >,
       'template': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewPageTemplateFile object at 0x7fc723f6d390>,
       'traverse_subpath': [],
       'user': <PloneUser 'lhmp1967'>,
       'view': <plone.portlet.static.static.Renderer object at 0x7fc71b031690>,
       'views': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewMapper object at 0x7fc71a67c790>}
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 217, in __call__
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 155, in _eval
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 117, in render
  Module plone.portlet.static.static, line 137, in transformed
  Module OFS.Traversable, line 317, in restrictedTraverse
  Module OFS.Traversable, line 285, in unrestrictedTraverse
   - __traceback_info__: ([], 'AuthenticatedUsers')
AttributeError: AuthenticatedUsers
```

Comment: Can't reproduce on an empty Plone 4.3.9. You have probably some 3rd party add-on or custom configuration that lead to this error.

Comment: Thanks @keul for all plone/zope help. It seems we have a solution on answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `plone.portlet.static Version 2.0.3` indicates you're using `Plone 4.3.4`, since Plone 4.3.3 has `plone.portlet.static Version 2.0.2` and `Plone 4.3.5` has `plone.portlet.static Version 2.0.4`.

The next Bugfix release of `plone.portlet.static (2.0.4)`fixes your Problem.
Check: https://github.com/plone/plone.portlet.static/commit/089012f2e4d7cf911c1361a3b0de334b3f1145c2

The portlet assignment context has been fixed for other categories than `context portlets`.

You may upgrade only the portlet to Version 2.0.4, or the whole site at least to `Plone 4.3.5`.

Comment: Thanks @Mathias, I will submit to our team and decide what way to fix our problem. After solved (I hope soon), we will post the results here.